# Android Firebase REST Issue

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-volley, firebase-realtime-database

For some reason I can't push my data to my firebase db. I'm trying to make a RESTful call using Volley to my db. What do you think I am doing wrong?

Issues that I am receiving:

```
12-23 19:16:43.026  15428-16461/me.anuraag.barter E/Volley﹕ [7289] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400 for https://barter.firebaseio.com/.json
12-23 19:16:43.028  15428-15428/me.anuraag.barter I/Error.Response﹕ com.android.volley.ServerError
```

Code:

```
public void firebaseSignUp(String emails){
    final String emailed = emails;
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
    String url ="https://barter.firebaseio.com/.json";

    StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.i("Repsponse",response);
        }
    },new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
           Log.i("Error.Response", error.toString());

        }
    }
    ) {
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("email", emailed);
            return params;
        }
    };
    queue.add(postRequest);
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to POST to firebase directly?

Comment: Yep, I am directly posting to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't do the `POST` yourself. Use the [Firebase API](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/api/) to handle all of that for you [per their examples](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/saving-data.html#section-set).

Make sure you are signed up with Firebase first. Then add this to your dependancies in your `build.gradle`:

> compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.0.3+'

Then to [save](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/saving-data.html#section-set) you could do something like:

```
Firebase usersRef = new Firebase("firebase.url.your/personal/dir").child("someChild");

Map<String, Object> users = new HashMap<String, Object>();
users.put("Dogs rule", someObjectWithAccessors);
users.put("Cats drewl", someOtherObjectWithAccessors);

usersRef.setValue(users);
```

Then to [retrieve](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-start), you could do something like:

```
// Attach an listener to read the data at our posts 
usersRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        Log.d(TAG, snapshot.getKey() + " received from firebase");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
        Log.w(TAG, "The read failed: " + firebaseError.getMessage());
    }
 });
```

Comment: The issue is I don't want to waste any connections because firebase only gives you a limited amount. Using their REST API straight up will not affect my connection amount.

Comment: I don't think you will have a way around it. There is a reason they have connections, and working your way around it will only prevent them from getting paid. So, I doubt there is a way, and I double they make it easy if there were.